# How to plot every second timestep? [r]

Tags: r

There must be a very easy way to do this but I don't know what it is...

As the title says, I would like to know how I can plot every second timestep of a time series in R? For example, I have half hourly data but I only want to plot the data on the hour e.g. I have

```
10:00 0
10:30 1
11:00 2
11:30 3
12:00 4
```

I just want to plot

```
10:00 0
11:00 2
12:00 4
```

Comment: Edit is an improvement, but can you be slightly more specific?  What is your data structure? Is it a data frame?  What class is the first column? (Use `dput()`/see http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ...) How would you plot the whole data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly less verbose and not quite as clear as Ben's solution but you can use vector recycling and indexing using a boolean to achieve this (as long as you're just interested in every other observation).

```
# Extract the data you want (assuming you want to keep
# the first observation and skip the second, ...
newdat <- x[c(T,F)]
plot(newdat)
```

Comment: Excellent! I just wanted something simple to view the data. This is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
plot(x[seq_along(x)%%2==0])
```

?

**Edit**: I don't know how you are plotting your data set above, but however you're doing it, you can subset your data as follows

```
halfhourdata <- fulldata[seq(nrow(fulldata)) %%2 == 1,]
```

If you give more details someone might tell you how to figure out which time values are hourly rather than relying (as here) on the fact that they are the odd-numbered rows ...